# Doing prediction after training the model on keras (Multiclass)?

Tags: python, keras

I am training a multiclass text classifier and I know that its naive question but I am naive to ML.

So I imported everything loaded the dataset which looks likes this

```
label  post
0      Don't worry
1      When did I?
2      By by
```

then I tokenized the sentences
and defined the model

Then trained it

```
model.fit(data, labels, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5)
```

Now how do I do the prediction for a custom text input ?

```
model_lstm.predict(?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `tokenize` and `pad_sequences` over your input string as you did for the training data, and then call `model_lstm.predict(tokenized_and_padded_string)` on it. 
This link has some code you can look at: [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-predictions-long-short-term-memory-models-keras/)

Comment: I did this `sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['post'])` So does it mean that I have to create a dataframe for every sentence to process it.@Priyank

Comment: You could collect multiple sentences into a dataframe and process them at once